# The shrew VPN client and configuration to connect to a McAfee (IKE Phase 1 IPsec Phase 2) VPN server

Tags: vpn, mcafee, shrew

On a Windows box I have a McAfee (McAffe VPN Client 5.9) client able to connect to a VPN server.

I'd like to connect from a Linux box.

I see the configuration and gateway on my Windows box has the following protocol:

```
IKE Phase 1 (Encrypt algorythms: AES - Mac algorythms: SHA-1) - IPsec Phase 2 (Encrypt algorythms: 3DES - Mac algorythms: SHA-1)
```

And the gateway configuration details:

```
IKE v1 IP
A user name and a password
Authentication method: hybrid
Encrypt algorythm: aes256-cbc
MAC algorythm: hmac-sha1-96
PRF algorythm: hmac-sha1
IPsec IP - IP
Encrypt algorythm: 3des-cbc
MAC algorythm: hmac-sha1-96
```

I understand I need to use a client that has the a ike/ipsec protocol.

I could build the Shrew one and am now trying to create a connection.

However it is asking me for a certificate file path when I try to save the connection dialog.

And I don't yet have one such certificate file.

What I have is a user login and a password.

But the connection dialog doesn't seem to care for this user name and dialog data, I cannot see where to type it in.